# Как сделать выполнения функции лишь по клику в setState?

Tags: reactjs

```
this.setState({
  Products:  products.map((product, index) => {
    return(
      <div className="catalog-item" onClick="console.log('click)" key={index} data-id={product._id}>
        <div className="catalog-item__top">
          <h4>{product.name}</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      )
  })
})
```

Проблема в том что onClick выполняется сразу при рендере( дальше функция не доступна)
Как сделать что бы она не выполнялось при рендере а только при клике на объект
Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div className="catalog-item" onClick={() => console.log('click)} key={index} data-id={product._id}>
  <div className="catalog-item__top">
    <h4>{product.name}</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```